# Angular-UI typeahead in ng-repeat as a conditional for certain properties/objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

Let's say I have this data that feeds into my ng-repeat:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Big Bird",
    "address": "abc street, san francisco california 00000",
    "object": [
      {"a": "b"},
      {"c": "d"},
      {"e": "f"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "address": "abc street, san francisco california 00000",
    "object": [
      {"a1": "b1"},
      {"c1": "d1"},
      {"e1": "f1"}
    ]
  }
]
```

How would I apply typeahead to this ng-repeat with two types of filters, one on address (using google maps geocoding api) and another on the nested item's values? Not all properties/objects will be present so I'm guessing it would have to be some sort of conditional. I know that the basic expression to use is: `<typeahead="x.z for x in y | filter:{z:$viewValue}">`

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I got it partially working so that it filters out one property. To pull from a particular property I used this in the HTML (example):

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in stuffs">
  <input ng-model="someModel" typeahead="obj as obj[display(obj)] for obj in stuff.object">
</div>
```

Angular discriminates if the 'object' property doesn't exist in every JSON object, so I included this in my $http.get in the controller so that when there's no property called 'object' an empty array is created for it:

```
angular.forEach(stuffs, function(value, key) {
  if (!value.object) {
    value.object = [];
  }
});
```

K cool. Now I want to limit the display results to just its values, not the keys, and for some reason typeahead wants to verify that these are in fact Objects, so I put this check in my controller:

```
$scope.display = function(myObject) {
  if (myObject && myObject.constructor === Object) 
    return Object.keys(myObject)[0];
};
```

So now we're filtering the 'object' property in our typeahead within the ng-repeat, meaning that wherever that property exists it will typeahead only the results for that object and not any other JSON object that contains the same property.

Now, my concern is that filtering doesn't work: it's filtering all options of that particular object's 'object' property, regardless of what is typed in. So that's where I am now, and also trying to figure out how to tie in another filter for another property (address).